# Prohibitory Symbol after Login [iMac Pro, Catalina]

Tags: catalina, login, imac-pro

after a clean install of catalina I have this weird problem that my mac shows the prohibitory symbol after I enter my password. However, if I enter it fast enough it will continue startup as normal. I don't know if thats a weird coincidence or some software messing with me. Confusing enough, the problem persisted after I made a new clean install (erase hard drive, boot from usb, install catalina).

- After entering password => Prohibitory Sign
- Clean installed twice
- Ran hard drive repair twice
- No weird kext installed (apart from cisco, dropbox and intel energy)

Looking forward,
Markus

Comment: Have you select, in System Preference, the Boot Drive?

Comment: yes, its also the only one

Comment: You can try do Reset SMC [https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295]  and Reset NVRAM [https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063] Then you unlock the padlock in Preferences/Boot Disk and you select your Boot Drive.